# How to get count of specific column on 3 table join?

Tags: mysql, database

Very new to joins and need some help. I have built a messaging system of kinds and I want to attach read/unread values to entire threads/conversations people are having. To that end I have 3 tables that relate specifically to threads:

`threads, posts, post_recipients`

```
threads
+ id
+ user_id

posts
+id
+ title
+ text
+ thread_id
+ author

post_recipients
+ id
+ post_id
+ recipient_id
+ status
```

I've found a way to get a list of threads, so now for each thread I want to query how many messages are read/unread based on a specific recipient.

This is what I've written so far but am getting an error "unknown column(posts.status) so I guess I'm doing either the sum wrong or the join:

```
select threads.id as thread, sum(posts.status = 1) as cnt 
from threads
left join (select thread_id, posts.user_id, status from posts left join post_recipients on posts.id = post_recipients.post_id) as posts on posts.thread_id = threads.id
where threads.id = 4;
```

Comment: According to your schema, there is no `status` column under `posts` but there is one under `post_recipients`.

Comment: I thought sum(posts.status) references the posts table alias created on the join?

Comment: Can you give an example of a data row for each of the 3 tables?

Comment: actually your comment was the answer. When I changed posts to post_list it worked. I guess it was just too ambiguous. If you make it the answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your schema, there is no `status` column under `posts` but there is one under `post_recipients`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using CASE

```
SELECT threads.id AS thread,
SUM (CASE WHEN post.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS read,
SUM (CASE WHEN post.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unread
...
```